IdentityServer4 with .Net7.0. API separation in SSO by ApiScope
I have 5 clients of my identity server, I need to separate the authorization of 1 client from the others. After signin to the ClientA, I switch to the ClientB already authorized, help me solve.
It is necessary for one IdentityServer to work as two?
my IdentityResourceStore:
public class IdentityResourceStore : IResourceStore {
        private readonly IScopeRepository _repository;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public IdentityResourceStore(IScopeRepository repository, IMemoryCache memoryCache) {
            _repository = repository;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<IdentityResource>> FindIdentityResourcesByScopeNameAsync(
            IEnumerable<string> scopeNames) {
            var resources = await GetAllResourcesAsync();
            return resources.IdentityResources.Where(r => scopeNames.Contains(r.Name));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ApiScope>> FindApiScopesByNameAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopeNames) {
            var resources = await GetAllResourcesAsync();
            return resources.ApiScopes.Where(s => scopeNames.Contains(s.Name));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ApiResource>> FindApiResourcesByScopeNameAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopeNames) {
            var resources = await GetAllResourcesAsync();
            var apiResources = resources.ApiResources.ToList();
            return apiResources.Where(x => x.Scopes.Any(y => scopeNames.Contains(y)));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ApiResource>> FindApiResourcesByNameAsync(IEnumerable<string> apiResourceNames) {
            var resources = await GetAllResourcesAsync();
            var apiResources = resources.ApiResources.ToList();
            return apiResources.Where(x => apiResourceNames.Contains(x.Name));
        }
        
        public async Task<IdentityServer4.Models.Resources> GetAllResourcesAsync() {
            var defaultResources = new List<IdentityResource> {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email()
            };
            ApiScope[] apiScopes = { new ApiScope("ClientA"), new ApiScope("ClientB") };
            var apiResources = new List<ApiResource>();
            if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("clients_array", out IEnumerable<string> clients_array)) {
                foreach (var clientId in clients_array) {
                    if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(clientId, out FileClient client)) continue;

                    if (clientId == ClientIds.ClientB) { 
                        var apiResource = new ApiResource(clientId) {
                            ApiSecrets = client.IdentitySeverClient.ClientSecrets,                        
                            Scopes = new [] { "ClientB" },
                        };
                        apiResources.Add(apiResource);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var apiResource = new ApiResource(clientId) {
                            ApiSecrets = client.IdentitySeverClient.ClientSecrets,                        
                            Scopes = new [] { "ClientA" },
                        };
                        apiResources.Add(apiResource);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new IdentityServer4.Models.Resources(defaultResources, apiResources, apiScopes);
        }
    }

One of the auth endpoints in my identityServer
   public async Task<IActionResult> AuthByPhonePassword([FromBody] AuthLoginPasswordDto authUserByPhoneDto) {
            var result = await _authService.AuthByPhonePassword(authUserByPhoneDto);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new IdentityServerUser(result.Value.UserId) {
                DisplayName = result.Value.UserName,
                AdditionalClaims = new Claim[] { new Claim(CustomJwtClaimTypes.UserType, result.Value.UserType) }
            }, null);

            return result.AsHttpResult();
        }

ClientA scopes: "scopes": "openid profile employee ClientA offline_access",
ClientB scopes: "scopes": "openid profile ClientB",
I attempted to separate different scopes. Tried to add a Policy on the API side, but this approach turned out to be unsuitable. It seems that my IdentityServer must be the one to indicate that a scope is not appropriate.
I noticed that after modifying resources, my JWT token began to change; the 'aud' list was correct (without any unnecessary clients), and the list of scopes in the token was also corrected.

Only way to do this, its when I disable caching on identity server (or set strict).
But it broke 'Auth without writing Log-Pass' logic in all APIs
